# Firebase messaging data comes to Android but not IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification

In my Flutter app, when I send push notification with Postman, the data is coming to my Android test device,

```
{notification: {title: MugSafe Powerbank Sizi Bekliyor, body: Hemen alışverişe başlayın}, 
data: {priority: high, data1: helloworld, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, 
content_available: true}}
```

but it is not coming to Ios simulator or real device even logcat.

It works as necessary in Android but not Ios

Should I do something in Xcode for this issue?

My post;

```
{
"to":"devicetoken",

 "notification": { 
    "body": "Hemen alışverişe başlayın",
    "title": "MugSafe Powerbank Sizi Bekliyor",
    "sound":"default",
    "sound2":"default",
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"

  },
  "data": {
    
   
    "data1":"helloworld"
   
  },
 "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: It's hard to provide insight when we cannot see the code that fetches the notification on your iOS app; can you please provide that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link where the setup for Cloud Messaging for iOS is explained (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration). After you did everything mentioned there, it should work as expected!

**Attention: Apple does not support notifications on their simulators!**